# How Can I Manually Lazy load image in Prestashop 1.6?

Tags: prestashop, lazy-loading, prestashop-1.6

I want to manually lazy load offscreen images from a prestashop 1.6 website, what would you guys recommend?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow! Please take your time to familiarise yourself with the site by taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), reading up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), going through [this brilliant question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and lastly, understanding how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Additionally, your question [lacks your attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Hope this helps you get more answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tons of modules for PrestaShop which will help you with this, all you need to do is browse official marketplace.

If you don't want to pay for this solution you can implement any LazyLoad library you want, PrestaShop doesn't have any special requirements for it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check on that

Answer (score 0):

In Prestashop lazy load image using upload & install stlazyloading module

this module is download by this link

https://www.sunnytoo.com/10743/free-prestashop-1-7-lazy-loading-module-for-product-images-to-speed-site

Above link you can manage lazyload